# How do I reuse parts of a strongly typed view in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm building a line of business application and when rendering the address, I have this piece of view code, which I really don't want to copy and paste everywhere:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Address.State, new
        SelectList(UsaStates.StateDictionary.OrderBy(s => s.Value), "Key", "Value",
            "Iowa"), "-- Select State --")
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address.State)
</div>
```

The Address class is very simple:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
}
```

The model classes implement the Address like so:

```
public class Business
{
   // .. other properties
   Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class College
{
   // .. other properties
   Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

With this, I have two views, Businesses/Create.cshtml and Colleges/Create.cshtml, with their own models.

What is the best way to make this snippet of view code available to all the views in my application whose models have address fields?

Answer (score 1):

You should make an [editor template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the example didn't really help. It's kind of outdated and it makes assumptions for ease of explanation. In my app, the Address property of the model is not scaffolded in the view creation, so the UIHint attribute is not effective.

Comment: @Robert: I've never done it myself, so I can't really help you here, but you should be able to create an editor template for the `Address` class and call it using `EditorFor`.  You shouldn't need to scaffold the column.  You could also write a partial view.

Comment: I started with a partial view strongly typed on the Address model, but I can't seem to figure out what to pass as the model on the RenderPartial() call, as I keep getting a "best overloaded method match" exception.

Comment: @Robert: You should be able to call `Html.RenderPartial("ViewName", Model.Address)`

Comment: I've narrowed it down. `@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.Address)` throws an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. `RenderPartial("_Address", Model.Address)` throws the "overload match" exception. Debugging Razor is kind of a pain, too.

Comment: This has already wasted too much time, so copy+paste it is. Maybe some day I'll be able to refactor it. Thanks for the help.